# SQL: Join on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to join the following tables:

- Table 1: users (id, name)
- Table 2: pivot_table (user_id, user_id2)

This table hold the relationship between the users. One user can be related to many other users.

- Table 3: contacts (id, user_id, name)

I am trying to select a user and then find its related users and contacts.
I have tried to use the join, i am successfully able to get either the contacts or the users but not the both.

I used the following query:

```
select
    contacts.id as contact_id,
    users.id as user_id,
    pivot.user_id2 as user2_id
from
    `contacts`
    inner join `users` on  `contacts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    inner join `pivot` as `pivot` on `pivot`.`user_id` = `contacts`.`user_id`
```

Suppose i have the following data in the tables

**Users:**

```
id   name
1    Sahil
2    Shubham
3    Xyz
```

**Pivot table data**

```
user_id   user_id2
1         2
```

**Contacts table data**

```
id   user_id   name
1    1         Abc
2    1         XYZ
```

**Now what is get from the query is**

```
contact_id   user_id   user_id2
1            1         2
2            1         2
```

but what i need is

```
contact_id   user_id   user_id2
1            1         null
2            1         null
null         1         2
```

I am not able to figure out what wrong i am doing.

Thanks

Comment: Your `INNER JOIN` syntax is incorrect, there is no `AND` between `JOIN` statements, so remove the `and` after the `user_id = users.id` part. Also you don't need to wrap every identifier in backticks.

Comment: oh sorry, i was using an query builder and collected that sql from it and forget to remove the AND from the query.

Comment: Is it working after removing "AND" between the two INNER JOIN? Also although it does not affect much but why are you using `pivot as pivot` if the alias is same as the table name?

Comment: It sounds like you want to perform a recursive search to find the contacts related to all users related to other users - this could be infinitely many layers deep. What data do you really want to return? Think it through. How would you collect the data if you were reading through printed pages of tables on paper?

Comment: yes it gives the correct result but the rows are still two. I need the result in three rows.

Comment: no i want to get the user and the contacts of 1 user. Not like user -> its related users and their related contacts. What i actually need is user -> related users -> related contacts of the same user for which i am finding the related users

Comment: 1121212121121112 how's anyone supposed to understand that?

Comment: post updated but it is quite clear that what the query returns and what table have what columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by myself with the use of Union to get the desired results.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT  B.id as contact_id, A.id as user_id, C.user_id2 as
user2_id
FROM `users` A LEFT JOIN `contacts` B
ON A.`id`=B.`user_id` LEFT JOIN `pivot` C
ON A.`id`=C.`user_id`;
```

See [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) for insight on using joins.

Comment: Still the result is same

Comment: see i also made an edit to my question, maybe that might help you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id,GROUP_CONCAT(contacts.user_id,pivot.user_id SEPERATOR ",")contacts.user_id,pivot.user_id
FROM contacts INNER JOIN users ON contacts.user_id=users.id INNER JOIN pivot ON users.id=pivot.user_id;
```

Comment: sorry but you completely missed the points which i mentioned. I need to join on the contacts.user_id not the contacts.id

Comment: you can change contacts.id by contacts.user_id

Comment: see again updatd answer

Comment: bro i tried the query by changing according to my requirement but the result is same which i got from my query.

Comment: use group concat only which column have multiple value of same id see again my question

Comment: Please explain what you did edit answer, avoid only code answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want a query to show unrelated data:

1. a user's contacts
2. a user's related users

I'd suggest two separate queries for this. If you want to do this in one query, use `UNION ALL`to combine two query results:

```
select contact_id, user_id, null as user_id2 from contacts
union all
select null as contact_id, user_id, user_id2 from pivot_table;
```